# Create a temporary table showing the most eventful country for each year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an exercise in SQL Server: I have two tables `Country` and `Events`.

The `Events` table holds the event details including the city where an event happens. The table `Events` has a foreign key `CountryID` (`CountryID` is the primary key in table `Country`).

I need to create a temporary table showing the most eventful country for each year.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest having a look at `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` as a good start.

Comment: This is the closest i get                    " 



select  year(e.EventDate) as YearOfEvent ,c.CountryName, count(e.CountryID) as NumberOfEvents from [dbo].[tblEvent] e
inner join tblCountry c
on e.CountryID = c.CountryID
group by e.CountryId ,c.CountryName , year(e.EventDate)
order by 
year(e.EventDate) asc" It is not right because i get more than one country for a specific year

Comment: Post your attempt in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: No one is going to read that attempt.  Format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't far off with your attempt, but you need to use a CTE to aggregate your data first. I've assumed that the final order of your data is important, so I used a second CTE, rather than a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` tio get the final result:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT YEAR(e.EventDate) AS YearOfEvent,
           c.CountryName,
           COUNT(e.CountryID) AS NumberOfEvents
FROM [dbo].[tblEvent] AS e
     INNER JOIN tblCountry AS c ON e.CountryID = c.CountryID
GROUP BY e.CountryId,
         c.CountryName,
         YEAR(e.EventDate)),
RNs AS(
    SELECT YearOfEvent,
           CountryName,
           NumberOfEvents,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YearOfEvent ORDER BY CTE.NumberOfEvents DESC) AS RN
    FROM CTE)
SELECT YearOfEvent,
       CountryName,
       NumberOfEvents
FROM RNs
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY RNs.YearOfEvent ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but ,This returns only one record and when i want to populate the temporary table all the rows will have this value .I have the timestamp for ex from year 1776 to 2016 .So i need the country for each year .This is it with I am working (https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/sql/exercises/standard/temporary-tables-and-table-variables/4231/)

Comment: My bad @AlbiFierGoxhaj missed out the partition (why having sample data is important as we can test). Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you,it works .Sorry I will be more accurate next time

Comment: You're welcome @AlbiFierGoxhaj. Please do remember the mark the answer as the solution if it solved the problem, so that future readers no that it was helpful. Plus you get reputation for it (which is really helpful for new users to starts earning those early privileges).